# SFTP file alignment issues

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp, sublime-text-plugin

I have sublime text 3 with SFTP plugin installed. Using it im able to download the code but the python files that are opened are not aligned properly.

I opened a ticket in SO but its not resolved.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/959866/files-improperly-aligned-after-transfer-via-ftp?noredirect=1#comment1533479_959866

Not sure I need to change in my py files either in the server or the editor. The lines are not aligned only after the SFTP.

My SFTP settings:-

```
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "tab_size": 8,
    "tab_width": 8
```

[image]

Comment: In all likelihood the file is indented with tabs and you have the `tab_size` in your Sublime preferences set to a value that's different than you expect.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the tab size in my remote is 8 but when I use the SFTP plugin its getting defaulted to '4'.. I have given my SFTP settings above.

Comment: SFTP supports no such settings; they should be in your user preferences (`Preferences > Settings`)

Comment: I tried changing my  package settings but when the file opens the tab size is set to 4 but not 8(which I want).

Comment: What do you mean by "package settings"?

Comment: I have given a snapshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation changes when viewing files on different computers or in different software are indicative of using tabs for indentation, as unlike spaces the amount of space that a tab takes up changes based on usage and configuration settings, and is one of the more hotly fought Holy Wars in the development arena.

As you have correctly surmised, you need to tell Sublime how wide you think a tab should be, since it's defaults are out of sync with what you expect.

For the most part your issue is that the settings you've mentioned in your post aren't SFTP Settings (the [available settings](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings) are in the [documentation](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)). SFTP just moves files around as a series of bytes, it's not involved with the actual display and editing of anything.

In order to get things to work better, you should put those settings in your user preferences. That's `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings` in the menu (i.e. press <kbd>⌘+,</kbd>) and add them to the settings pane on the right.

That said, note that `tab_width` is not a setting that Sublime understands by default, although the other three you mentioned are valid. Additionally those settings will cause Sublime to expand all tabs into 8 spaces, removing the tab characters entirely.

Assuming you don't want your files to be indented with tabs any longer, that's what you want. If you prefer tabs, you should set `translate_tabs_to_spaces` to `false` instead, so that tab characters are retained.